# Why does the content owner needs a CMS account to retrieve revenue data from youtube api?

Tags: http-status-code-403, oauth, forbidden, content-management

I am trying to retrieve revenue details from YouTube API from content owner's account (using OAuth) but I am getting the same 403 response. Do the content owner needs a CMS account to retrieve revenue data from youtube api?

Comment: Your question title includes why, and then the final question is "does"? Are you after a yes/no answer or further detail?